# Selection.InsertFile() not finding file despite it being in directory

Tags: c#, console, ms-word

I am experimenting with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace to do some manipulation of docx files, specifically programmatically merging them.

I created a simple test harness to try out some of the functionality and I am getting a file not found error despite the file being in the executing directory.

All I am trying to do is merge two docx files, doc1.docx and doc2.docx respectively. Again I am just playing around with this functionality at this point so I created a simple C# console app and have the following:

using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

```
//and in my method:
object defaultTemplate = @"Normal.dotm";
object missing = System.Type.Missing;
object outputFile = "out.docx";


Word.Application wordApplication = new Word.Application();
//using the default Word template
Word._Document wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(defaultTemplate);
Word.Selection selection = wordApplication.Selection;
//add files manually. THIS is where things are failing
selection.InsertFile("doc1.docx");
selection.InsertFile("doc2.docx");
```

I get an exception with the message "This file could not be found." in my first call to InsertFile(). I am certain the files exist in my debug directory, which is where this program is running. MSDN explicitly states that if you don't provide a path with your parameter it uses the current directory. It finds the template Normal.dotm fine. I feel like I am missing something simple here but have been messing with it for over a half hour with no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should be doing here? Thanks for reading!

Comment: You spent a half hour and then wrote this entire thing but couldn't try with full path?! wow

Comment: Hmmm you are right of course. My brain is just mush this afternoon. Of course I should have tried just using the full path. I got so focused on "this should be working without a path" that I didn't just use the simplest solution that should have been staring me in the face.

Comment: Btw, full path doesn't have to be the answer. But it sure helps debug ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure for your path is available. use `GetCurrentDirectory()` to be sure your current directory is what you want. else use full path.

Answer (score 1):

You also might need to set the default file path.

```
MyWordApp.Application.Options.set_DefaultFilePath()
```

Comment: Yeah.  They ran out of stuff to give me, so I just sit here reading stackoverflow and pretending to look busy.

Comment: Nice. I broke my the code branch i'm working in so i'm stacking and trying to fix it.

Comment: Lets switch to gchat. this is probably sending notifications to 10 different people